# Highlight all words that appear in particular spellfiles, differently

Tags: syntax-highlighting, spell-checking

I have a document with several custom words. To spell check these, I have sorted words into multiple word lists written in the "straight word list" format (detailed at `spell-wordlist-format` in Vim documentation), and accordingly modified the `spellfile` setting to include these.

However, I would like to be able to quickly highlight all words that appear in a particular word list, and be able to toggle that highlighting on/off at will. It seems like there should be an elegant way to match the words in a particular list, perhaps using the generated `.spl` files? (Seeing as this is already what Vim effectively does, just for spell checking purposes.)

Right now, I have a makeshift solution of typing `:set spellfile-=./wordlist1.utf-8.add` to highlight everything as wrong, and then when I'm done with looking at the highlights, revert this. But it would be nice to not have to fiddle with the spellfile option and to be able to look at multiple word lists highlighted in different colors.